# DNS services uses cellular data even when it's disabled

Tags: iphone, ios, dns, cellular-data

I have noticed this happening for over 3 months now, on both my old phone and the new one I got, which wasn't backed up from the old one. If I disable wifi, then go into the system services usage statistics, DNS services will have used any where from 5-40 kb of data, despite the fact that cellular data is still disabled.

I've also had it where, after resetting statistics, both it and push notifications have went up, again, despite cellular data being disabled.

Best way to reproduce is reset statistics, then disabled wifi.

Has anyone else experienced this, or is anyone else able to reproduce this?

Edit: To clarify, I am aware DNS lookups happen on both cellular and wifi. But the statistics go up on cellular when both it and wifi are disabled.

Comment: Why would DNS lookups stop just because you turned wifi off?  DNS lookups still need to happen if you do anything on the internet so it will use your cell service if wifi is not available.

Comment: Per my post, this happens when mobile data is disabled along with wifi. ie it goes up when I disable wifi, but before I turn on mobile data.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem although I hadn’t noticed it went up with both celullar data and WiFi disabled. With this information I have come with an hypothesis that explains this:

The first thing that the client does when trying to connect to a service is to interact with the DNS server to ask for the IP of the service.
When both cellular data and WiFi are off, the client will fail to connect to the DNS server and will probably just keep trying, sendind packets over and over again.
The good news is that this happens locally on the device and thus the traffic doesn’t go trough your internet provider. If many apps are doing this constantly, it could add up to gigabytes of “traffic”.